# Rails 3.2 - Get String Representation of 'create' Action URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have just finished implementing WePay into my e-commerce website, and part of the API requires me to specify a redirect URI to which users will be redirected after their purchase. I would like to get the string representation of the create URI that the user will be redirected to so that, after the purchase, an Order object will be created. I have to specify the redirect URI in the 'orders#new' action, and so I'm wondering if it is possible for me to get the URI for the 'create' action of that order and pass it into the API call for WePay.

I have tried using the [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for) method like so:

```
@order = Order.new

redirect_uri = url_for(@order)
```

Unfortunately, this does not bring me to the 'create' action of the order but instead the 'index' action. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass it a hash, forcing the CREATE action.

url_for(controller: 'orders', action: 'create')

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry for the very late reply; I actually decided to switch from WePay to PayPal. However, I can see this being useful to others.